# Filter, get url before controller (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, dispatcher

I want to write filter, and get client `httprequest` before controller and make some code, depends on URL.

Request can be: `HttpRequest`, `MultipartHttpServletRequest`, can be `POST` or `GET`. I need to make request to another REST API, if the URL of this request starts with `api`.

Comment: Sure that will work. Just implement "[Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)" from the servlet api and map it to your Spring dispatcher servlet. Or you might keep using a Spring controller (avoiding a filter) and write a rest client to connect to the foreign system. Id prefer the latter.

Comment: I tried to use controllers. But I have path with slashes, and it not working for it. For example user sent request "http://myserver/api/email/1". I need to write in controller "value = "api/{path}"". Path should be equal "email/1", but path cannot contain slash. I don't know how many slashes can send client inside httprequest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Spring [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

(hopefully [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8297463/280244) explain how to use it)

*(or you could use an simple Servlet-Filter - see also this question [Spring HandlerInterceptor vs Servlet Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000844/spring-handlerinterceptor-vs-servlet-filters) it discuss the difference between them)*